# Reactor - Após filter false, realizar chamada para outro método

Tags: java, kotlin

Dado o código abaixo:

```
fun method() {
    return gateway1.getPerson(id)
        .filter { isPersonValid(it) }
        .flatMap { gateway2.isPersonHasAddress(id) }  // Retorna Mono<Boolean>
        .filter { it }
        .switchIfEmpty { Mono.just(false) }
}

private fun isPersonValid(person: Person) {
    // verifica se é valido
}
```

É possível depois de cada filter .. caso retorne false, chamar um método para logar alguma coisa ? Ai após isso cair no switchIfEmpty ?! Lembrando que o log que é a ação de exemplo é diferente para os dois, então não necessariamente daria pra por a chamada dentro do switchIfEmpty

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você está procurando é o operador [doOnDiscard](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#doOnDiscard-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Consumer-), projetado para cenários como esse:

```
return gateway1.getPerson(id)
    .filter { isPersonValid(it) }
    .doOnDiscard(Person.class, person -> {
        // somente pessoas que foram descartadas pelo filter
        logPerson(person)
    })
    .flatMap { gateway2.isPersonHasAddress(id) }  // Retorna Mono<Boolean>
    .filter { it }
    .switchIfEmpty { Mono.just(false) }
```

Usei como exemplo `Person.class`, mas você pode substituir pela sua classe.